# How to draw a horizontal line in a bar plot?

Tags: pgfplots

I want to draw a horizontal line in a bar plot. However, I got an unsatisfactory result (as the figure below).

I have no idea how to modify the code to achieve the following effect:

1. remove the node value 3.0 at both sides;
2. add a word 'neutral' in the center below the line (the word in the figure is added by myself);
3. extend the line to the boundary at both sides.

Could anyone help me with that?

[image]

```
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
x,ave,med
Launch,3.93,4
Options,4,4
Text Input,4.38,4
Text Display,3.35,3.5
Fixed-item List,3.44,3
Dynamic-item List,4.32,4
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
% \usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
% \usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[tb]
\centering
\hspace*{-0.32cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\scriptsize]
    \begin{axis}[ybar,
    height=4.5cm,width=9cm,
    ymin=0,ymax=6,
    ylabel style = {align=center},
    ylabel={\# relevant score},
    ytick={1,...,5},
    symbolic x coords={Launch,Options,Text Input,
    Text Display,Fixed-item List,Dynamic-item List},
    xticklabels={,Launch,Options,Text Input,
    Text\\ Display,Fixed-\\item List,Dynamic-\\item List},
    xticklabel style={align=center},
    nodes near coords, 
    nodes near coords align={vertical},
    nodes near coords style={/pgf/number format/fixed,/pgf/number format/fixed zerofill,/pgf/number format/precision=2},
    every node near coord/.append style={font=\scriptsize},
    ]
    \addplot table [x=x,y=ave,col sep=comma]{data.csv};
    \addplot[red,line legend,sharp plot,
    update limits=false] coordinates {(Launch,3) (Dynamic-item List,3)};
    \end{axis}

    \begin{axis}[
        axis x line={none},
        ymin=0,ymax=6,
        ytick={1,...,5},
        height=4.5cm,width=9cm,
    ]
    \addplot[only marks,mark=*,mark size=2pt,magenta,
            ] table [x expr=\coordindex,y=med,col sep=comma]{data.csv};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
x,ave,med
Launch,3.93,4
Options,4,4
Text Input,4.38,4
Text Display,3.35,3.5
Fixed-item List,3.44,3
Dynamic-item List,4.32,4
\end{filecontents*}

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
% \usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
% \usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[tb]
\centering
\hspace*{-0.32cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\scriptsize]
    \begin{axis}[ybar,
    height=4.5cm,width=9cm,
    ymin=0,ymax=6,
    ylabel style = {align=center},
    ylabel={\# relevant score},
    ytick={1,...,5},
    symbolic x coords={Launch,Options,Text Input,
    Text Display,Fixed-item List,Dynamic-item List},
    xticklabels={,Launch,Options,Text Input,
    Text\\ Display,Fixed-\\item List,Dynamic-\\item List},
    xticklabel style={align=center},
    nodes near coords, 
    nodes near coords align={vertical},
    nodes near coords style={/pgf/number format/fixed,/pgf/number format/fixed zerofill,/pgf/number format/precision=2},
    every node near coord/.append style={font=\scriptsize},
    ]
    \addplot table [x=x,y=ave,col sep=comma]{data.csv};
    \addplot[red,line legend,sharp plot,nodes near coords={},
    update limits=false,shorten >=-3mm,shorten <=-3mm] 
    coordinates {(Launch,3) (Dynamic-item List,3)} 
    node[midway,below,font=\bfseries\sffamily]{neutral};
    \end{axis}

    \begin{axis}[
        axis x line={none},
        ymin=0,ymax=6,
        ytick={1,...,5},
        height=4.5cm,width=9cm,
    ]
    \addplot[only marks,mark=*,mark size=2pt,magenta,
            ] table [x expr=\coordindex,y=med,col sep=comma]{data.csv};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]